# How do I send data based on 3 list size in JSON

Tags: java, json

I have 3 input fields which is repeated 10 times. For example name,age and qualification.For first 3 rows I'am giving the value for each input fields and for the last 3 rows I'am giving the value for each input fields. I have added name, age and qualification values in an nameList, ageList and qualList object.

Now I want to send this through JSON like this format.

```
"studentsInfo": {
"students": [
  {
    "name": "aaa",
    "age": 21,
    "qualification": "B.E"
  },
  {
    "name": "aaa",
    "age": 21,
    "qualification": "B.E"
  },
  {
    "name": "aaa",
    "age": 21,
    "qualification": "B.E"
  }
]
```

}

How do I iterate these 3 Lists in a for loop.

It might be a very simple question. But I feel difficulty to understand this and structuring a loop.

Please give me an idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ [name : aaa, age : 21, qualification : B.E] [name : bbb, age : 21, qualification : B.E] [name : ccc, age : 21, qualification : B.E] }
```

Is not [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/). I think you mean like this

```
[
    {
        "name" : "aaa",
        "age" : 21,
        "qualification" : "B.E"
    },
    {
        "name" : "bbb",
        "age" : 21,
        "qualification" : "B.E"
    },
    {
        "name" : "ccc",
        "age" : 21,
        "qualification" : "B.E"
    }
]
```

If you have 3 lists each with the values for different objects, then you could iterate through them like this:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

for(int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i ++) {
    String name = nameList.get(i);
    int age = ageList.get(i);
    String qual = qualList.get(i);
    personList.add(new Person(name, age, qual));
}
```

Then you could serialize the `List<Person>` using a library like [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

This assumes you have a java bean `Person` with the fields `name`, `age`, and `qualification`:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    String qualification;

    public Person(String name, int age, String qualification) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.qualification = qualification;
    }
}
```

The JSON library you use will serialize `Person` objects into JSON.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a valid json, you are looking for something like this i suppose, first show us what you have tried so far, we cant give a helpful answer if you havent tried anything first

```
  "studentsInfo": {
    "students": [
      {
        "name": "aaa",
        "age": 21,
        "qualification": "B.E"
      },
      {
        "name": "aaa",
        "age": 21,
        "qualification": "B.E"
      },
      {
        "name": "aaa",
        "age": 21,
        "qualification": "B.E"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then read a little about [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) it can do the mapping for you

Comment: yes you are correct. I mentioned in a wrong way.Sorry for that. May i know how can I achieve this by using loop?

Comment: james newman gave you an insight about how to do the for loop but he is supposing you already built a model and mapped it with some library, which i think you should do first before worrying about the loop